# ansible ec2.py / boto EC2 validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm writing a playbook to validate our Cloud Formation stacks (port 80 open, httpd.conf has correct settings, instance type is correct, etc).  The one thing that is tripping me up is how to validate EC2 tags.

```
key=Name, value=testec2
```

I've tried the below and changed the when condition multiple different ways.

```
- name: Check Name Tag
  action: debug msg="Name Tag Exists."
  when: "ec2_tag_Name"
```

[Examples tried]

```
when: "tag_Name_testec2"
when: " ec2_tag_Name_testec2"
when: "ec2_tag_Name"
```

I've actually tried quite a few more varieties but those are the ones I can easily remember off the top of my head.

when i run "ec2.py --list"  it outputs multiple formats of the tag

```
"ec2_tag_Name": "testec2",
"tag_Name_testec2": [
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to check if an instance with `tag:Name` as `testec2` is in the inventory?

Comment: after building a stack, i'm writing a playbook to validate. For the tags, i'm validating that certain keys exist.  The value is less important but If I can can validate both key and value, that would be most awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I use tag_Name_testec2 but this is a group in hostsvars. Is not a common variable. To avoid troubles, first change in your ec2.ini, the cache max age, from 20 to 1:

cache_max_age = 1

and see if you have some filter like region or public or private ip.

You could debug you hostvars with this way:

```
[batman@myhost myproject]$ ansible -i ec2.py tag_Name_webserver -u ec2-user -m debug -a msg="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ec2_id'] }}" -vvv
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
10.78.17.117 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "i-b34cb736"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Raul for the suggestion.  I will give the cache_max_age a try and report back.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, I finally figured it out. Feel free to point and laugh for not noticing "is defined" missing.

name: Check Name Tag Types
action: debug msg="Name tag exists."
when: "ec2_tag_Name is defined"